# bootstrap css is not loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I prepared my bootstrap website using visual studio and it works properly.
But when I try to run html file through going in that folder then bootstrap css is not loading.

Can you tell me the reason behind this?
Thanks in advance

Here is my head section

```
<link href="../font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<title > K.P Facility Management</title>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../images/title.png" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you view the page source and click on the css URL, does it take you to the correct path? Are you sure that your path is correct?

Comment: Loading 2 different versions of jQuery won't end well.

Comment: Off - Topic **This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced** It's hard to us find the problem on this kind of situations

Comment: @BillyMoat the power of bad frameworks :P But yeah, using both 2.1 and 1.11 is surely the worst what can one do.. I'd stick with 1.11

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the paths are wrong. With the "../" before your path, you're going up a level from the root, which will return an error (if you look at the inspector).

Try placing this html in the folder that contains the folders you are going to use files from, and change the paths to:

```
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```